# How to send a xmlhttp request to a php file to upload an image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried to make an ajax image uploader I was wondering how to send an image via a xmlHttpRequest .

Firstly i tried to send with a  FormData object

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file',fileInput.files[0]);
```

But when I do `print_r` in the requested php file to `_POST` and `_FILES` but the function returned an empty array .

I tried also doing it with only the send() method but it also doesn't work where is the problem

Note : i didn't forgot the `"multipart/form-data"` in the setHeader.

Comment: Can you paste your AJAX call please ?

Comment: Don't set the`multipart/form-data` header and pass formdata to send()

Comment: @SofianeSadi I am using a personalized function if you want i will update my question with the function

Comment: It will be good @Abdessalem

Answer (score -1):

To use the XML HTTP request features in your application, you must learn to upload files on the background with Ajax

1) Define the input elements for the file upload. Use the upload() method for the button click event to upload the file when the button is click.

```
 <input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" />
 <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="upload()" />
```

2) In the upload() method, create a FormData interface instance, and add the file element with the attached file into it. Use the send() method to send the FormData to the server.

```
  <script>
     var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

     function upload() 
     {
        var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

        /* Create a FormData instance */
        var formData = new FormData();
        /* Add the file */ 
        formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);

        client.open("post", "/upload", true);
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
     }

     /* Check the response status */  
     client.onreadystatechange = function() 
     {
        if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
        {
           console.log(client.statusText);
        }
     }
  </script>
```